# Cadastral Fabric 9.3

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-9.3, basic-license-level, parcel-fabric

I am using ArcView without any extensions.  Is there an alternate program out there which uses Cadastral Editing (Parcel Editing) or something similar?

I downloaded the ArcEditor 10.0 trial version but the parcel editing does not function as I don't know if its due to it being trial.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

60 Day and 180 day trial at ArcEditor Level will give you "Cadastral Editing"

The following extensions are included with all ArcGIS for Desktop free trial versions.

```
ArcGIS 3D Analyst
ArcGIS Data Interoperability
ArcGIS Geostatistical Analyst
ArcGIS Network Analyst
ArcGIS Publisher

ArcGIS Schematics
ArcGIS Spatial Analyst
ArcGIS Tracking Analyst
ArcScan for ArcGIS
Maplex for ArcGIS
```

For **Cadastral Editing (Parcel Editing)** you need to setup the Data as Parcel Fabric in ArcCatalog:

A parcel fabric is created through a wizard in the Catalog window and appears as a new node under a feature dataset. When creating a parcel fabric on an enterprise geodatabase, you have the option to set a configuration keyword, which specifies storage and location parameters for optimal space and disk location efficiency.

Guide:
http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#/Creating_a_new_parcel_fabric/008500000004000000/

[image]

Then load in your data into ArcMap and find the 
Parcel Editing tool.

NOTE:
Once a parcel fabric is loaded into ArcMap, you can choose to either directly edit parcels in the map (automatic edit mode) or work with job workflow functionality (manual edit mode).
http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#/Tutorial_Getting_started_with_parcel_fabric_editing/001t00000154000000/

If you need more advanced editing features the COGO extension is required.
THIS IS NOT INCLUDED and you will need to contact ESRI to get a evaluation key code to upgrade the trail to ArcEditor/ArcINFO license with the extension enable.

Parcel Fabric

[image]

Comment: thanks..i'll try it in the morning and let you know the outcome, Mapperz.

Comment: This is part is all brand new to me and am lost -  is there anyway I can IM you, Mapperz or someone else?  Either MSN, yahoo, skype etc? I do appreciate it.

Comment: Have you uses ArcCatalog to create a Geodatabaase? Then Create Parcel Fabric dataset... http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#/Creating_a_new_parcel_fabric/008500000004000000/

Comment: The part which is frustrating is it would be nice if the arcgis helpdesk would simplify how to do things.  I don't know if there is a certain order in doing a Parcel Fabric (I've created it)..  how to add data to it, where from, etc... 

It's frustrating as I've googled this topic online without much luck.

Comment: see updated image on the answer - NewFabric is created from alachuacounty_polygon, alachuacounty_arc & alachuacounty_point

Comment: Mapperz, for parcel fabric, is there a book or something similar to a book on parcel fabric?  for some reason, I feel like a dummy with it.  I need to learn it.

Comment: most of the documentation is in the help for ArcGIS. But the Online Help is updated more often.